# How to deploy 100s of jars in Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I was in the process of converting java projects build system from **Ant to Maven** and there are literally 700+ dependency jar files lying in a folder without any version or package information.

I was able to figure out maven co-ordinates for 400+ of those jar files using it's hash. So for the remaining 300+ jar files I am thinking of uploading it directly to a local repo in Artifactory and then generate maven co-ordinates automatically.

As far as i have [explored](https://www.theserverside.com/video/4-ways-to-upload-a-JAR-to-a-JFrog-Artifactory-repository) the only way to achieve this is to deploy/upload every jar file manually via Artifactory UI with *Deploy as Maven Artifact* option enabled to generate co-ordinates automatically but this is a very time consuming process (I want to do this for 300+ files).

is there any other efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to achieve what you want, unfortunately none is available "out of the box"...

1. Use the command line client to upload each JAR file to Artifactory.
   The main command to upload is:

   jfrog rt upload foo.jar maven-local-repo

See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory for more details

Use a bash script to loop on the JAR files, and for each file, upload it to a separate location, generate a short pom (from a sample pom and some sed to replace groupId and artifactId with the filename) and upload it next to the JAR file.

2. As Artifactory provides this option over its webapp, create a Selenium client that loops on each JAR file, connects to the Artifactory UI, and uploads each file using the "Generate default POM" option.

See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Deploying+Artifacts#DeployingArtifacts-DeployingMavenArtifacts

Comment: Thank for you answer @arnaud. I have already started implementing 2nd option but I think your 1st option is also worth exploring. will keep you updated

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you already figured out a solution, but for anyone else who has to do something similar I ended up just using gradle to do it for me. I created a bare gradle project and with the following build.gradle. It collects all the jars from the directory specified and loops through them and creates publications for each. We wanted to use the sub-folder structure as the groupId so there's a bit of logic to format that in there.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.21.0"
    }
 }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

version = '0.2021.0'

ext.thirdPartyLib = fileTree(dir: "$rootDir/../extrajars", include: ['**/*.jar'])
    
    publishing {
        publications {
           thirdPartyLib.each{ jar->
              def fbase = jar.name.minus(".jar")
              "$fbase"(MavenPublication) {
                 artifact jar
                 artifactId fbase

                 //the following was to use the folder structure as the groupId
                 def path = jar.path.minus("\\" + jar.name)
                 path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", ".")
                 path = path.replaceAll("c:/pathtoDirectory", "")

                 groupId = path
              }
           }
        }
     }
     
     artifactory {
        contextUrl = 'http://yourArtifactoryUrl'
        publish {
           repository {
              repoKey='yourRepo'
              username='username'
              password='password'
           }
           defaults {
             thirdPartyLib.each{ jar->
                def fbase = jar.name.minus(".jar")
                publications( fbase )
              }
           }
        }
     }
```